# finding unique multiple similar strings of json between {}

Tags: python, json, regex, string

I'm trying to match multiple sets of unquoted/invalid json in a string in a python script.

This is an example of the string im trying to parse

`string = ' json.piece({ id:001, dictionary_id:0013, weight:"10" });  json.piece({ id:002, dictionary_id:0075, weight:"01" }); json.piece({ id:007, dictionary_id:0010, weight:"54" });'`

My current regex is:

```
result = re.findall(r"(\{[^}]*\})", string)
```

Instead of finding the individual pieces it finds the entire string as its also technically true but I, despite trawling though stackoverflow, cannot seem to find a solution

Comment: wow, i missed one character! thanks so much im still learning regex, cant belive it was that simple

Comment: you must believe , happy coding :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `(\{[^}]*?\})` to make your `regex` non-greedy